# Github Pull Request from Develop branch to Master branch shows previous commits .How can I avoid such issues?

Tags: git, github

We have branches like: `feature/branch`, `develop` and `master`

When I have created a PR from `feature/branch` to  `develop`, I see only one commit and only changes to my files in the `feature/branch` which is good and have merged into  `develop` branch

Then for some reason when I have created a PR from `develop` --> `master`. It shows a whole list of previous commits and changes even if I've made only a single line change in `develop`

How do I resolve such issues and avoid having such in every Pull request

Comment: Does your PR have its base branch as `master` or `develop`?

Comment: base: Master <- compare develop

Comment: How many commits are in `develop` that are not in `master`, created by you or others?

Comment: @Kar Your PR is merging `develop` into `master` so you're going to see changes between `develop` and `master`. If you want to merge your feature branch into `develop` you want a base of `develop` and a compare of `feature/branch`.

Comment: I have reverted back the `develop` branch to the previous state before I pushed the `feature/branch` ..The commit counts are matching b/w `develop` and `master`   Then I have compared base `master` with `develop` and I see 3 commits and files .. I am not able to understand this ..Also, the origin for us is `develop` branch .. `develop` branch and `master` branch shows same count and commits but when compared why does it shows 3 commits which are already in `master`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have avoided such issues by avoiding `Squash and Merge` in the GitHub. And Have rebased the feature branch with `git pull --rebase origin`

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it does not grow out of the question. The question said "have merged into develop branch". You did not tell us you were doing squash and merge. Squash and merge, despite the name, _is not a merge._ So the whole problem is that you did _not_ merge into develop.

Comment: `Feature branch to Develop is Merge `
Develop branch to Master branch is Squash and Merge